# Can't find element selenium python

Tags: python, windows, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

```
<input placeholder="Enter Password" class="password-input" type="password">
```

Above is the element I am trying to send keys to using the below code.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import StaleElementReferenceException, TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe')

driver.get('https://howsecureismypassword.net/')

elem = driver.find_element_by_name('password-input')
elem.send_keys('password')

html = driver.page_source
```

This is the error I get and can't figure out why.

```
 RESTART: C:\Users\bakat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\Science 

Experiment\Science_Experiment_Password_Tester.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\bakat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\Science Experiment\Science_Experiment_Password_Tester.py", line 18, in <module>
    elem = driver.find_element_by_name('password-input')
  File "C:\Users\bakat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 365, in find_element_by_name
    return self.find_element(by=By.NAME, value=name)
  File "C:\Users\bakat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 752, in find_element
    'value': value})['value']
  File "C:\Users\bakat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 236, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\bakat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 192, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"name","selector":"password-input"}
  (Session info: chrome=57.0.2987.133)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.27.440174 (e97a722caafc2d3a8b807ee115bfb307f7d2cfd9),platform=Windows NT 10.0.14393 x86_64)
```

This is the site - https://howsecureismypassword.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `find_element_by_class_name` instead of `find_element_by_name`.

Looking at the HTML of your site, the **class name** of the element you want is `password-input`, not the name.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import StaleElementReferenceException, TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe')

driver.get('https://howsecureismypassword.net/')

elem = driver.find_element_by_class_name('password-input')
elem.send_keys('password')

html = driver.page_source
```

Comment: I still get the same error but with this changed --- selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"class name","selector":"password-input"}

Comment: Maybe try putting a wait in between `driver.get` and the `find_element` line. Sometimes selenium moves too fast for it's own good, and tries to find an element on a partially loaded page. Try importing `time` then putting the line `time.sleep(5)` in between `driver.get` and `elem=driver.find_elem..`. That's an extremely long wait, but it should show if that's the problem.

Comment: You were right Christopher Apple it works now - Thanks!